# Keep Facebook Session open

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've currently implemented facebook login in my android app without the use of the LoginButton.

I have my own button and once the user clicks it, I open an Active Session.
If the session state is open i pull the AccessToken and store it locally. I than make a Graph Request and get the ID returned from GraphUser. This id is also stored locally.

Once I have an AccessToken and GraphUser ID, I use the two values in my own backend api to either create or log into a app specific account.

Is their any reason I should keep the Facebook Session open after all of this is  done successfully.

I can add code if needed but not sure how much more it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, in the current version of sdk, you can close the active session by

`Session.getActiveSession().close()` 
and you will still be able to access graph api through the access token you saved. However this is not encouraged because you actually have no reason to close a Session, because it holds no connection to be freed, only a access_token string.

There is no reason to close or keep active Facebook Session, but there is reason to use Facebook Session to access graph api.

1. The session would broadcast about it's status changing automatically, which would make it easy to follow your user's status.
2. Graph API will keep changing in new versions. Using SDK is the easiest way to follow up and avoid app crashing on the API updating.

Hope this would help!